# Generic setter function for local properties in PHP

Tags: php, oop, setter, private-members

I'm planning to log any modifications to certain properties of an object.

PHP has a magic method `__set` to overload any attempts to modify (private) properties from outside an object.

However, this does not apply from inside the object. **Is there a way in PHP to have a generic setter function for any calls to modify a local propery of an object?**

---

*Example:*

```
class Thing
{
  private $data;

  public function editData()
  {
    $this->data = 'edited';
  }

  function __magic($property, $value)
  {
    if ($property === 'data') {
      print 'Data is being edited!';
    }
  }

}
```

I would want the `__magic` function to be called before the `$data` is edited.

Comment: Even SPLSubject expects you to call the notify() method explicitly: I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, inside the object all the properties are accesible and don't need a magic method. But if you want to asign your properties throw a function, you only have to do a slighty modification in your code:

```
class Thing
{
  private $data;

  public function editData()
  {
    $this->propertySetter('data', 'edited');
  }

  function propertySetter($property, $value)
  {
    if ($property === 'data') {
      print 'Data is being edited!';
    }
    $this->$property = $value;

  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but this requires the methods to use a the custom method, I was looking for a transparent solution. Oh well, I thought it's probably not possible.

Comment: No, I think that is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You could use __call like so:

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    if(preg_match('/^set_/', $name)) {
       $attr = str_replace('set_', '', $name);
       $this->{$attr} = $args[0];
       if ($attr === 'data') {
          print 'Data is being edited!';
       }
    }
}
```

And in your constructor:

```
$this->set_data('edited');
```

**EDIT**

You can use a combination of __call and __set to get your functionality working.

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
  $this->{"set_$name"}($value);
}
```

This will allow you to execute set_attr when using object `$obj->attr = ''`;

Comment: But `__call` is not called when editing a local property, as in `$this->data = 'bar';`

Comment: But even then, `__set` is not called when editing a *local* property, within the object. It only works from outside the object on a private property (ie. when there's no access to the property), otherwise the property is edited directly.

Comment: Yes, sorry this is the most universal way of doing this I could think of.